# An operator whose adjoint has dense range is injective

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

How can I solve this question:

> An operator $A$ whose adjoint has dense range is injective.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Show that $A^{\ast\ast}$ is injective.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $Ax = 0$ for $x$ in your Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Then note that for all $y \in \mathcal{H}$, we have $0 = \left \langle Ax, y \right \rangle = \left \langle x ,A^*y \right \rangle$, so $x$ is orthogonal to the range of $A^*$. But it is also orthogonal to the closure of the range of $A^*$, which is $\mathcal{H}$. Thus $x=0$ so $A$'s kernel is trivial. Therefore, $A$ is injective.

I'll leave it to you to fill in the details, like showing that $x$ is orthogonal to the closure of the range of $A^*$.